# Kafka Schema Registry - when we use this do we need to keep all the historical avro files in the codebase?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

We have an application - which has many components mainly microservices and
we have kafka and schema registry getting installed as part of application package.
In the code package of each application - we have avro files and we register them to schema registry on start of the application.
My doubt is when the schema starts evolving say from v1 to v2, v3 ,v4 in different releases of our application, do we need to keep all the avro files of schema v1, v2,v3,f4 in the application?

I need this because lets say in MyApp- release v1  - i have v1 Avro schema

MyApp- release v2 - i have v2 Avro schema

etc like that

And a customer at MyApp - release v1  is going to upgrade to MyApp - release v4

And now i now that v4 version of schema is not compatible with v1 version of schema
hence the schema registration will fail at the Schema registry. (Because schema registry at customer place had v1 release)

To avoid such problems thinking to keep all the versions of schema in the application and
register them one by one sequentially.
Like how liquibase schema migration happens.

Is this the good idea or any better approaches exist with Schema Registry for this type of usecase?

Answer (score 0):

> at customer place had v1 release

This wouldn't matter. The consumers and producers are decoupled, and the Registry doesn't know about either, only the schemas it has (which are generally registered only by producer clients before data is sent)

Since the registry is backed by a compacted topic, it persists all the schemas on its own. In practice, the only reason I've seen to keep schemas all locally is to write migration code in the event of breaking compatibility (and setting registry subject config to none, post the new schema, then set it back to the default)

Comment: The problem is the SchemaRegistry is also part of the application, so the registry at the customer place - will have V1 version only.
And when he skips some of our releases and directly goes for release 4,
that has V4 schema which is not compatible with V1.

Comment: The location of the registry server doesn't change my answer